# Multiple hosts in connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

when iam trying to add 2 hosts to my programm so i can reach the server from within / without local workgroup by using domain or ip, i allways get the message that i could not reach one of those servers.

Using only one of the hosts results in success, however using both does not

```
String connString = "Server=hpscloud.de:3306,192.168.10.1:3306;Database=" + database + ";uid=" + username + ";password=" + password;
```

Can you guys tell me what iam doing wrong ?

Comment: I have created a simple connection manager that you can use for MySQL .Net connector and it would allow you to use a multi-host connection string, see [this github project](https://github.com/HoomanBahreini/MySQLConnectionManagerForNet)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's MySql.Data claims to support multiple hosts in [its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html):

> Multiple hosts can be specified separated by commas.

(The [documentation linked in the other answer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ConnectionString.htm) that says `&` has a typo and is incorrect.)

Unfortunately, support for comma-separated hosts has been broken for many years: [bug 81650](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81650).

To get support for this feature, switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (which fixes this and [many other MySql.Data bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs)).

Note that the port can't be specified as part of the hostname; it has to be specified with the `Port=` option (or omitted since `3306` is the default). Your connection string should be:

```cs
String connString = "Server=hpscloud.de,192.168.10.1;Database=" + database + ";uid=" + username + ";password=" + password;
```

Also check out the [`LoadBalance` option](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/) to control how connections are made across the servers you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Server names should be separated by the `&` char

As per documentation

> The name or network address of the instance of MySQL to which to
>   connect. Multiple hosts can be specified separated by &. This can be
>   useful where multiple MySQL servers are configured for replication and
>   you are not concerned about the precise server you are connecting to.
>   No attempt is made by the provider to synchronize writes to the
>   database so care should be taken when using this option.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ConnectionString.htm for further information

Comment: sadly, the documentation does not supply me with an example. just changing the "," between the ip's to & does not help :(